# Why does make return errors when compiling mesa?

Tags: makefile, mesa

I am trying to compile mesa (as part of the compilation process for xcrysden) and I have an error in the make process that I don't understand how to fix. I am quite unfamiliar with using make so any support is appreciated. I checked other threads on stack overflow and I didn't see answers to this specific problem.

```
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/elliot/software/xcrysden-1.6.2/external/src/mesa-18.3.6/src/mesa/drivers/dri'
  CXXLD    mesa_dri_drivers.la
/usr/bin/ld: i965/.libs/libi965_dri.a(libintel_common_la-gen_disasm.o):/home/elliot/software/xcrysden-1.6.2/external/src/mesa-18.3.6/src/intel/common/gen_disasm.c:31: multiple definition of `INTEL_DEBUG'; i965/.libs/libi965_dri.a(libintel_common_la-gen_debug.o):/home/elliot/software/xcrysden-1.6.2/external/src/mesa-18.3.6/src/intel/common/gen_debug.c:39: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: radeon/.libs/libradeon_dri.a(radeon_debug.o):/home/elliot/software/xcrysden-1.6.2/external/src/mesa-18.3.6/src/mesa/drivers/dri/radeon/radeon_debug.c:60: multiple definition of `radeon_enabled_debug_types'; r200/.libs/libr200_dri.a(radeon_debug.o):/home/elliot/software/xcrysden-1.6.2/external/src/mesa-18.3.6/src/mesa/drivers/dri/r200/radeon_debug.c:60: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[6]: *** [Makefile:719: mesa_dri_drivers.la] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/elliot/software/xcrysden-1.6.2/external/src/mesa-18.3.6/src/mesa/drivers/dri'
make[5]: *** [Makefile:814: all-recursive] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/elliot/software/xcrysden-1.6.2/external/src/mesa-18.3.6/src/mesa/drivers/dri'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:3385: all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/elliot/software/xcrysden-1.6.2/external/src/mesa-18.3.6/src/mesa'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2200: all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/elliot/software/xcrysden-1.6.2/external/src/mesa-18.3.6/src/mesa'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:895: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/elliot/software/xcrysden-1.6.2/external/src/mesa-18.3.6/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:680: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/elliot/software/xcrysden-1.6.2/external/src/mesa-18.3.6/src'
make: *** [Makefile:692: all-recursive] Error 1
```

The errors:

```
make[6]: *** [Makefile:719: mesa_dri_drivers.la] Error 1
```

```
make[4]: *** [Makefile:3385: all-recursive] Error 1
```

```
make[1]: *** [Makefile:680: all] Error 2
```

Clearly the error is something to do with the drivers, but I do not understand what the error messages are trying to tell me.

Comment: Although there's a lot of info, it seems pretty clear to me.  The first one says that the symbol `INTEL_DEBUG` is being defined twice; once in `gen_disasm.c` line 31 and the second time in `gen_debug.c` line 39.  You can only define each global symbol one time in the program, else the system doesn't know which one you mean when you refer to them.  Similar for the other error.

Comment: `make` is not the problem.  It's just the tool that *discovered* the problem.  Supposing that you have not made any modifications to the software, the issue very likely is either that the Mesa distribution you are trying to build is buggy, or that you `./configure`d it in an unsupported way, or both.  We do not have sufficient information to be more specific, and in any case, the Mesa team would be better equipped to help you with details of building their software.